# Cannot access textDocumentProxy protocol functions in Swift

Tags: swift

My class is a subclass of `UIInputViewController`. I want to access the `textDocumentProxy` object of `UIInputViewController` such that I can call `insertText` on `textDocumentProxy`.

From the documentation, `textDocumentProxy` conforms to `UITextDocumentProxy` which conforms to `UIKeyInput`.

Based on the above logic, why can't I simply do the following.

```
self.textDocumentProxy.insertText("Hello World")
```

Instead I get the following error

> 'NSObject' does not have a member named 'insertText'

Do I have to do some sort of special casting?

Here is a snippet of the documentation.

```
class UIInputViewController : UIViewController, UITextInputDelegate, NSObjectProtocol {
    var textDocumentProxy: NSObject! { get }   
 }

protocol UITextDocumentProxy : UIKeyInput, UITextInputTraits, NSObjectProtocol {
    var documentContextBeforeInput: String! { get }
    var documentContextAfterInput: String! { get }
}

protocol UIKeyInput : UITextInputTraits, NSObjectProtocol {
    func hasText() -> Bool
    func insertText(text: String!)
    func deleteBackward()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call this method on single line like this

```
(self.textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).insertText("Hello World!")
```

or

```
(self.textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).insertText("Hello World!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to downcast twice because of the inherited protocols.

`let textDocument = self.textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput`